# Multi-threaded queue consumer and task processing

Tags: c#

I'm writing a service that has to read tasks from an AMQP message queue and perform a synchronous action based on the message type. These actions might be to send an email or hit a web service, but will generally be on the order of a couple hundred milliseconds assuming no errors.

I want this to be extensible so that other actions can be added in the future. Either way, the volume of messages could be quite high, with bursts of 100's / second coming in.

I'm playing around with several designs, but my questions are as follows:

1. What type of threading model should I go with? Do I:

   - a) Go with a single thread to consume from the queue and put tasks on a thread pool? If so, how do I represent those tasks?
   - b) Create multiple threads to host their own consumers and have them handle the task synchronously?
   - c) Create multiple threads to host their own consumers and have them all register a delegate to handle the tasks as they come in?
2. In the case of a or c, what's the best way to have the spawned thread communicate back with the main thread? I need to ack the message that came off the the queue. Do I raise an event from the spawned thread that the main thread listens to?
3. Is there a guideline as to how many threads I should run, given x cores? Is it x, 2*x? There are other services running on this system too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *generally** avoid direct thread programming in favor of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) and concurrent collections built into .NET 4.0 and higher. Fortunately, the producer/consumer problem you described is common and Microsoft has a general-purpose tool for this: the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.100).aspx).  [This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/03/c.net-little-wonders-concurrentbag-and-blockingcollection.aspx) has a good summary of its features.  You may also refer to [this white paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/PerformanceCharacteristicsOfThreadSafeCollection.pdf) for performance analysis of the `BlockingCollection<T>` (among other things).

However, before pursuing the `BlockingCollection<T>` or an equivalent, given the scenario you described, why not go for the simple solution of using the [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.100).aspx).  The TPL gives you the asynchronous execution of tasks with a lot of extras like cancellation and continuation.  If, however, you need more advanced lifecycle management, then go for something like a `BlockingCollection<T>`.

---

* By "generally", I'm insinuating that the generic solution will not necessarily perform the best for your specific case as it's almost certain that a properly designed custom solution will be better.  As with every decision, perform the cost/benefit analysis.